# Swift iOS -Difference in calling a function on the main queue from what's inside the function on the main queue?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Inside my app I have several things that get enabled in the completion handler below but for simplicity purposes I just used one button for this example. I only say this because someone will look at the example and say since there is only 1 button to make things simple use the 1st option which would make sense for 1 button but not several. Also this question can pertain to anything that runs on a different thread then then main thread and not a CaptureSesion.

I have an AVFoundation CaptureSession completion handler that is on a different thread then the main queue. When it runs it updates a button to `.isEnabled = true`.

I can either

•1. update the function on the main queue directly:

```
... completionHandler{(

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.recordButton.isEnabled = true
    }
)}
```

•2. put the button inside a function and then update that function on the main queue:

```
... completionHandler{(

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.enableRecordButton()
    }
)}

func enableRecordButton(){
    recordButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

•3. update both the function and what's inside the function on the main queue:

```
... completionHandler{(

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.enableRecordButton()
    }
)}

func enableRecordButton(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.recordButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

**What's the difference between the 3?**

Comment: Not much, in no. 2 you are adding an additional function call and in no. 3 you are adding two. thats the only difference. performance wise it wont make a difference.

Comment: 1 and 2 are identical (unless in 2 you have some other reason for needing`enableRecordButton` to be a separate method), and 3 is stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule you should update the UI components only on main thread. Hence

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
       self?.recordButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Makes absolute sense. Because you would like the button to be enabled and it is a UI modification you would want it to be in main thread. So all the statements in the closure of `DispatchQueue.main.async` will be executed on main thread.

Where as in

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
       self?.enableRecordButton()
}
```

The method `enableRecordButton` will be executed on main thread. That means all the statements in `enableRecordButton` method and all the subsequent methods it calls will be executed on main thread.

In your case, if all that you wanna achieve is enabling a button than putting it in a separate function would not make much sense. Only benefit that you get is that you would be able to enable the button by calling `enableRecordButton` function from wherever you want rather than repeating same statement again n again.

Finally

```
... completionHandler{(

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.enableRecordButton()
    }
)}

func enableRecordButton(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.recordButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

This in your case makes no sense. Statement

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.enableRecordButton()
    }
```

will already ensure that all statements in `enableRecordButton` would execute on main thread so adding `DispatchQueue.main.async`  in `enableRecordButton` makes no sense.

```
func enableRecordButton(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.recordButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

This might come handy only if you have multiple points in your code from where you might call `enableRecordButton` and might call it on non-main thread in that case you can safely remove

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
           self?.enableRecordButton()
    }
```

and simply call `self?.enableRecordButton()` in your completion handler and  `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `enableRecordButton` function will ensure that all the statements will be executed on main thread.

Hope it helps

Comment: hey thanks for the help. When you said "In your case..." In the very first paragraph of the question I said "inside my app I have several things that get enabled in the completion handler below but for simplicity purposes I just used one button for this example...". I know for 1 button just use option 1. Thanks for your help. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @lance-samaria : Sorry I forgot that you had mentioned that this is a diluted version of complicated problem :) Hence happened to mention in your case :) Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding DispatchQueue.main.async { } again in the function is useless because you are already on the main thread, which you need to update the user interface. Suppose you have certain task which you need to schedule after update of button you can add another DispatchQueue.main.async { } to put it in serial queue which will be executed after updation of button. But in every case updations will be done on main thread only and those will be serial.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, all three would achieve the same result.  It's more about code organization, maintainability, and readability.

For #1, you're likely doing business logic in your completion handler that has nothing to do with updating UI.  It'd be cleaner to move the UI updating to its own method, say, in the UIViewController whose view owns that button (and the other UI controls you mentioned).  Benefits of doing so are that you can enable your UI controls via the same call from elsewhere in your app, and you can write tests against it.  You can *also* better test your business logic of this completion handler, if you had a way to redirect the UI update call (such as via a protocol, to a mock).

And #3 is a waste, in that you're wasting a yield, adding a task to main thread, just to ensure the UI code will be on the main thread.  You should instead organize your classes and code to always have a good understanding of what thread they're to be called from.  If you're writing a public method in an SDK, you can certainly check the thread and assert if caller calls on a thread other than you expect, but that's about the only time I'd bother with that.

So my answer is #2 is the best.